# What is the name of the circle theorem stating that any three non-colinear points define a unique circle?

Tags: geometry, circles

Can anyone tell if there is a name for the circle theorem which states that any three non-colinear points define a unique circle? Or how may I reference such statement. Perhaps I am too thorough about this?!

Comment: Hopefully no name.

Comment: It's simply "an easily-provable result from elementary Euclidean geometry". (As noted in, say, [this recent answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4438011/409), the "Euclidean" qualifier is important.)

Comment: Euclid's Elements, Book IV, Proposition 5.  http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0086%3Abook%3D4%3Atype%3DProp%3Anumber%3D5

Comment: Maybe "existence and uniqueness of circumcircle of triangle"?